# wso2 identification server paging user

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I test wso2 identification server admin UI, seems user list do not support pagination - search result can only be in one page.

Also the API cannot support paging.

Can somebody give some guidances how can I retrieve search result more than 1 page?

Answer (score 0):

Pagination is supported by the management UI in Identity Server...  AFAIK, UI would only retrieve 6 pages for one time. BTW What is the identity server version you are using? (I am talking about latest version which is 4.6.0).  Also in API, you can find that, Limit and a  regexp pattern can be passed to BE to retrieve users. Therefore, you can limit number of users what is read from user store.  You could find the WSDL from following url

`https://localhost:9443/services/UserAdmin?wsdl`

Comment: Hi, I have tested several times, it only show limited rows record to me, both for UI and wsdl. BTW, I do use 4.6.0. Is it possible caused by some path? I didn't apply any patch.